# Angular E2E Test with Code Coverage

Tags: angular, protractor, code-coverage, angular-cli

I am using Angular v4 with angular-cli to build.  We are just starting to look at e2e testing.  The CLI recommends protractor.  Is there anyway to get code coverage for protractor e2e test?  Only things I have found so far is to use grunt.  Really would like to stick with angular-cli.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no way to run an E2E test with coverage report using angular CLI.

Feature request https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6286 has been already exist.